# C# Fastest way to send large web api response across the network

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core 8 Web API that reads Json data from a file and sends the data back in an IActionResult response. When I test the code locally with Postman, I get the response in approximately 2 seconds. When I deploy the same code to our QA environment, Postman gets the response in 38 seconds.

Is it possible to receive 22 Mb of data in a response in three or four seconds?

My current code:

```
[HttpGet, Route("/api/GetData/{callingApp}")]
public IActionResult GetData(
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$"), Required, MaxLength(50)] string callingApp)
{
    string fileName = _config.GetSection("DataPath").Value;
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
    var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return Ok(data);
}
```

Comment: Rather than read everything into memory first, have you tried returning a `FileStreamResult`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for the fast reply. Will a FileStreamResult give me faster response times?

Comment: The best way to tell if one thing is faster than another is to test it. You can make guesses, but guesses can be wrong. So why not just try FileStreamResult and see if it makes a significant change? See also [Which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by eric lippert.

Comment: You're wasting time and RAM by loading the data in memory instead of returning it directly. You can replace almost all of the code with `return File(fileName);`. You didn't specify whether POSTMAN is on the same machine as the web app in the QA environment though. You can't expect a remote call to be as fast as localhost access